# How to remove an item from a list

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've got a list of text strings created from (listA and listB are named ranges):

```
=UNIQUE({listA;listB})
```

How would I need to change this formula to exclude the value "XXX", if it were to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE({listA;listB}),UNIQUE({listA;listB}) <>"XXX")
```

Comment: Thank you SOO much. I've been wracking my brain to figure this out for quite some time.